# How to extract data from the EntityCollection?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the following LINQ statement:

```
var test = db.Employees.Include(Constants.EF_SecondaryTeamAllocationToApprovers)
                    .Where(e => e.ApproverEmployeeId == SessionObjects.LoggedInUserId)
                    .Select(e => e.SecondaryTeamAllocationToApprovers);
```

This returns an `IQueryable<EntityCollection>` object.

I am not familiar with the `EntityCollection` collection. I am finding that I cannot extract the properties from this object. For example the following loop does not work, I get a null instead:

```
foreach (var item in test)
{
    list.AddRange(item.Select(s => s.SecondaryTeamLeaderId));
}
```

I find when I drill inside the control the correct data is there, I just need to extract it.

So how do I fix this?

Comment: are you getting an exception? my guess you prob want to materialize the test var by appending .ToList() so the items are pulled down from sql..

Comment: No exceptions. I get one item in the collection - which is what I expect although I intend to test of many later. For that one item, I cannot get the SecondaryTeamLeaderId property.

Comment: And the const ef_SecondaryTeamAllocationToApprovers is definitely the same as the navigation prop on employees? Btw wat is SecondaryTeamLeaderId? An int or a ref type?

Comment: To the first question, yes. It is a constant so avoid spelling mistakes. SecondaryTeamLeaderId is an int.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in test)
{
    list.Add(item.SecondaryTeamLeaderId);
}
```

OR

```
list.AddRange(test.ToArry());
```